# Do I need to pay if I have more than 5 apps on Heroku?

Tags: heroku

I deployed 5 very simple React apps on Heroku.
Today, when I wanted to add a 6th one, Heroku came up with the error message:

> You've reached the limit of 5 apps for unverified accounts. Delete
> some apps or add a credit card to verify your account.
>
> Account Verification Required Your account must be verified to create
> this app. Please add payment information to verify your account.

For verification Heroku basically needs me to give them my payment details.
Doe's it mean that from the 6th app, Heroku is going to charge me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heroku will only charge you for paid services. If you continue to use only free dynos and free add-ons you shouldn't be charged.

Note that [you might initially see some holds](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/account-verification) on your card:

> Every bank works differently, and some of them require a one dollar hold by the verifier before a card can be confirmed. After a few business days the hold will be released and your card will be verified if successful.
>
> If you see multiple instances of a $1.00 charge, it may be because the card information was submitted multiple times. The duplicate holds will also be released and returned to your account after a few business days.